# How to specify type of value via 'TypeRep'?

Tags: haskell, dynamic, types, polymorphism, generic-programming

My aim is to write function that takes some polymorphic values and list with typereps representing concrete types. It returns new list with the same values but already casted to concrete types specified via typereps.

Let we have such list of values: `["one", "two"]` with `-XOverloadedStrings` enabled.
Respectively, type of each one is `IsString a => a`.

List of typereps we could get in such way:

```
import Data.Typeable (Proxy(..), typeRep)
import Data.Text     (Text)

[typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy String), typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy ByteString)]
```

Is there any way to get `"one"` of type `String` and `"two"` of type `ByteString`?

P.S. To prevent error according to list containing values of different types, we may wrap every value in `Dynamic.`, as in the example below(pseudocode):

```
 {-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

 import Data.Dynamic (toDyn)

 [ toDyn (val :: type') | val <- vals | type' <- concreteTypes ]
```

*It could be done using Template Haskell, but it will be too ugly.*

Comment: What would be the type of the resulting list? Something like this is likely possible using the new reflection machinery, but you'd need to return an HList at the very least.

Comment: A list can only consists out of *one* type of elements.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Edited.

Comment: @Alec In my situation it should be turned into dynamic later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't really imagine your purpose, but the code will probably look something like this. I'm using the new `Type.Reflection` interface because I'm more familiar with it than with the classic `Data.Typeable`, but that should work for this too.

```
import Type.Reflection

types :: [SomeTypeRep]
types = [SomeTypeRep (typeRep @String), SomeTypeRep (typeRep @Text)]

strings :: [String]
strings = ["one", "two"]

converted :: [Dynamic]
converted = fromJust $ zipWithM convert types strings

convert :: SomeTypeRep -> String -> Maybe Dynamic
convert (SomeTypeRep rep) s
  | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep rep (typeRep @String) = Just $ toDynamic s
  | Just HRefl <- eqTypeRep rep (typeRep @Text) = Just $ toDynamic (fromString s)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Classic `Data.Typeable` won't work for this too: it doesn't offer `eqTypeRep` to get a type-level equality, only term-level equality. You'd need `unsafeCoerce` or similar instead.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I had in mind. I love the new `Type.Reflection` module. :)

Comment: Also this seems to require you to know the list of possible types one might ask for ahead of time, right? (Here one couldn't add `SomeTypeRep (typeRep @ByteString)` to `types` without modifying `convert` -- so `convert` can't be forward-compatible with new instances of `IsString`.)

Comment: @DanielWagner `convert` is really doing a lookup in a dependent map (keys being types `T`, values being functions `String -> T`) and then applying the function. A more general implementation would accept as input any such map, making it extensible in such a way.

Comment: @user2407038 Hey, guess what, `fromString` is doing that too! Why not reuse that machinery? (...like my answer does, hint hint.) (Also that mapping isn't dependent. Dependent goes `term -> type`; this goes `type -> term`.)

Comment: @dfeuer Your desicion based on typereps comparison fit me the most. Thank you =)

Answer (score 4):

Hold my beer.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.String
import Data.Text (Text)

data Forall c where Forall :: (forall a. c a => a) -> Forall c
data Exists c where Exists :: c a => a -> Exists c
data Evidence c where Evidence :: c a => proxy a -> Evidence c

instance c ~ IsString => IsString (Forall c) where
    fromString s = Forall (fromString s)

asProxyType :: proxy a -> a -> a
asProxyType = const id

downcast :: Evidence c -> Forall c -> Exists c
downcast (Evidence proxy) (Forall v) = Exists (asProxyType proxy v)

polymorphicStrings :: c ~ IsString => [Forall c]
polymorphicStrings = ["one", "two"]

types :: c ~ IsString => [Evidence c]
types = [Evidence ([] :: [ByteString]), Evidence ([] :: [Text])]

monomorphicStrings :: c ~ IsString => [Exists c]
monomorphicStrings = zipWith downcast types polymorphicStrings
```

To connect with the question as asked: `Exists Typeable` is isomorphic to `Dynamic`. You might need to generalize `Forall, Exists :: Constraint -> *` to `Forall, Exists :: [Constraint] -> *` to comfortably support both `IsString` and `Typeable` at once, which is a bit of type-level hacking but nothing too strenuous. Type families can give you an `Elem :: Constraint -> [Constraint] -> Bool` which can be used to replace `c ~ IsString` everywhere above.

Comment: P.S. I am very sad that `[] @ByteString` doesn't work.

Comment: Seems, it doesn't solve the problem of specifying type based on [TypeRep](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#t:TypeRep).

Comment: @errfrom Correct, you must specify it based on `Evidence` or the new [`TypeRep :: k -> *`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html). But I don't see this as an issue: just replace `typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)` with `Evidence ([] :: [a])` everywhere (or save both if you need the `typeRep` for other uses); it's even characters saved.

Comment: @DanielWagner True, but what should that do in the presence of `OverloadedLists`? In that case, the application should likely be for container type rather than the contained type.

Comment: @Alec So what if it doesn't work with `OverloadedLists`? Lots of things break when you turn on pragmas.